# How server actions flows from the VF page

Tags: apex

I am new to salesforce.

Can someone please give me a simple example of implementing server actions from the VF page.

Comment: please go through this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_intro_architecture.htm

Answer (score 1):

1. Many Visualforce components have an action attribute, this allows you to specify a controller method. To have a look at the possible VF components, have a look at the [Visualforce Developer guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/) , more specifically the Standard Component Reference.
2. Your page needs to be connected to a custom or extention controller through either the `controller` or extensions `attribute`. The value of the attribute is simply the class name of your controller.
3. In your Apex controller, create methods. Passing parameters is possible.

Very basic dummy code:

```
    <apex:page controller="testController" >
      <apex:commandbutton action="{! doStuff}" value="click me" />
    </apex:page>

    public class MyController {
         public void doStuff(){
            //logic
         }
    }
```